# If a connection returns to the pool while a thread is blocked waiting on a new connection to be created, will the returned connection be used?

Tags: c#, ado.net, connection-pooling

Basically the scenario I'm considering is the following:

Lets say it takes a significant amount of time to create a new connection.

All connections are in use and a thread requests a new connection.

While the thread is waiting for the new connection to be made, a connection returns to the pool.

Will the thread wait for the new connection to be made and use that or will it unblock right away and use the returned connection.

I tried to test this, but I was having trouble with getting the right timing between 2 threads (very variable connection times).

Comment: Whatever the answer is, what would you intend to change about *your* code? You generally don't have to think about what the connection pool is doing down to this level. If this is "I've got this weird set of symptoms and if it's X rather than Y that may explain the symptoms", please share the symptoms with us, not the current theory.

Comment: How are you returning it to the pool, and which pool do you mean (there can actually be more than one: a process pool and a system-wide pool).  also, I think that it may matter what you are connecting to.

Comment: HI @Damien_The_Unbeliever There won't be any big changes to my code due to this. It may however impact my choice for the minimum size of my connection pool. I'm also just interested in knowing.

Comment: Hi @RBarryYoung I am concerned with SqlConnection, I am closing it with .close(). The process pool is what I was referencing in my question. I wasn't aware of system-wide pooling thanks for bringing that up!

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I forgot to mention I would probably opt to use synchronous code within each thread if the thread is blocked until the new connection is returned. The queries are pretty light, and the new connection creation time (500 ms) overhead significantly impacts performance. Since the service is IO bound, theres not much work to be done while waiting on a response.

Comment: The SqlServer driver/access library implements a system-wide pool, that goes back to COM days (before .Net).  ADO.Net implements its own process-pool.

Comment: If you're worrying about the connection pool then you probably have bigger problems. You need to dipose all connection objects with `using`, not just calling `.Close()`, if you don't you can get waiting connection problems

Comment: @Charlieface `using` is the recommended way to manage connections from code, but not the only correct way to manage a component like an ADO.Net connection.  Specifically, `.Close()` works fine, so long as you insure that it is actually called.

Comment: @RBarryYoung True, but something *somewhere* needs to properly manage the connection and attempt to dispose it correctly even in the event of failure. A bare `Close()` without a `finally` is simply not good enough. Without seeing any code we don't know, but commonly people either cache the connection object, or don't bother closing at all.

Comment: @Charlieface I do have it in a using, I just do a .close() as well before the end of the using which is probably bad practice. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @Charlieface  `.Close()` is enough, you just have to insure that it is called.  You are assuming a certain model of accessing SqlServer ("context-less") that connects, does something, and then disconnects.  There are programs that need a more complex model that keeps a connection open because it has session context that needs to be re-used.  In these cases, you cannot use `using` because the connection and the disconnection are not in the same methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question:

> While the thread is waiting for the new connection to be made, a connection returns to the pool.

My understanding of how this works for ADO.Net and the SQL Server driver is that if the thread is "*waiting for the new connection*" there is already an active connection object in your thread/process in the `connecting` state.  Neither the ADO.Net connection manager, nor the SQL Server drivers have any facility to "switch" that connection object for another connection object from the pool if one were to become available.

So once you initiate a connection, you keep that object until you close it (or otherwise discard it).

Also, you may already know this, but the connections in the pool are not actually disconnected, rather they are in an *inactive* state where they are physically connected but not logged-in to the server.

Answer (score -1):

**This is Wrong** as pointed out in the comments, the session IDs are different.

I came up with a simple way to test this. I can't believe I didn't think of this earlier.

The results show a blocked thread waiting for a new connection to finish being created will unblock if a connection returns to the pool (and use the returned conenction)!

For those of you wondering, the new connection that was in the process of being started is still added to the pool.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace General_Testing
{
    class Program
    {
        private static volatile bool returned = false;
        private static string connStr = "your connection string here";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(thread1);
            Thread t2 = new Thread(thread2);

            t1.Start();
            t2.Start();
        }

        private static void thread1()
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Restart();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                conn.Open();
                returned = true;
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Thread1 created thread in " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");
                Thread.Sleep(50); //new connection takes much longer than 50ms to be created
            }
        }

        private static void thread2()
        {

            while (!returned) ;
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Restart();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                conn.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Thread2 created thread in " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the results:

```
Thread1 created thread in 2098ms
Thread2 created thread in 194ms
```

Comment: Don't you have to make `returned` volatile or interlock it?

Comment: You shouldn't have to, it's not a problem if thread2 reads returned as false for a few iterations after thread1 sets it to true. Rerunning the test with bool as volatile gives the same results.

Comment: It wouldn't be just one iteration, it's until the CPU cache gets reloaded (i think).

Comment: I get 464ms and 2ms. But I also (outside of the timing logic) run `SELECT @@SPID` on both connections and they report different numbers - so they're actually different connections. So I don't see what this proves.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You are right it is getting a different session ID. This is quite weird to me since the second connection is made so much faster than the first, is it an authentication thing?